# Form Responses (Google) - Email Trigger

Tags: google-forms

how do you create a email trigger on a google responses form?

There is a question on my form that says "would you like to be contacted by your Property Manager to discuss further?" Ideally if the answer is yes to this question, I would like to response sheet to fire an automatic email to the relevant PM as a notification to make contact.

Answer (score 0):

There is a notification add-on which you can get for free from the Add-ons menu. Unfortunately it can't be triggered by a check-box, you can only specify after how many responses should he email you.

Comment: Thanks, the issue is we have 27 Property Managers and I need to somehow direct the response to the specific PMs not through to the form creator.